# Igualar primer elemento de tupla a una lista python

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Tengo la siguiente tupla, quisiera crear una lista a partir del primer elemento de cada posición.

Lista =[16,259,209,...,179]
Muchas gracias de antemano

> [[(16, 0.12143221), (259, 0.07235707), (209, 0.06686923), (254,
>   0.056732856), (85, 0.052190553), (186, 0.047896527), (170, 0.03725162), (8, 0.033070035), (154, 0.029168405), (315, 0.028492954), (163, 0.027874647), (4, 0.027425438), (60, 0.025618345), (296,
>   0.023605729), (162, 0.02343925), (89, 0.023149906), (94, 0.022124302), (100, 0.021779122), (145, 0.020460771), (179, 0.019821487)

Comment: Holaa Gibran ¿Has intentado algo? ¿Qué problema concreto o error tienes? Por cierto, ¿tienes una lista con otra lista dentro o es un error? Me refiero a que tienes `[[(...` y no `[(...`

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo 2 soluciones

Usa una comprensión para iterar y obtener el primer valor de cada tupla,

La mejor para mi es convertir a un arreglo de NUMPY (biblioteca externa muy útil), luego piensa que tus datos son filas y columnas de una tabla, usa la sintaxis de rango [:,0] significa quieres todas las filas, pero solo la columna 0,

Te dejo el código de ejemplo para ambos casos

```
import numpy as np

mi_tupla = [
(16, 0.12143221), 
(259, 0.07235707), 
(179, 0.019821487)]

# Solución 1 usando comprehension, itera tu lista para obtener el primer valor
lista_primer_valor = [tupla[0] for tupla in mi_tupla]
print(lista_primer_valor)

# Solución 2 usando un arreglo de numpy luego parte
mi_array = np.array(mi_tupla)
array_primer_valor = mi_array[:,0]
print(array_primer_valor)
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacerlo con un bucle **for** así:

```
lista_primer_elemento = [] #creamos una lista vacía 

for tupla in Lista[0]:
    lista_primer_elemento.append(tupla[0])
```

Entiendo que faltan dos corchetes al final de tú pregunta con los que inicias. Por lo que **tienes una lista, que contiene otra lista**, que está es la que contiene las tuplas. por lo que **accedemos a la primera lista usando Lista[0]**, después iteramos por las tuplas de la segunda lista con el bucle **for**, en cada tupla **seleccionamos el primer elemento con tupla[0]** y por último lo añadimos a una lista nueva con el método **append**.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la función `map()` para realizar una operación para cada valor, y luego hacer una lista con el resultado.

```py
lista_de_tuplas = [(16, 0.12143221), (259, 0.07235707), (209, 0.06686923), (254, 0.056732856), (85, 0.052190553), (186, 0.047896527), (170, 0.03725162), (8, 0.033070035), (154, 0.029168405), (315, 0.028492954), (163, 0.027874647), (4, 0.027425438), (60, 0.025618345), (296, 0.023605729), (162, 0.02343925), (89, 0.023149906), (94, 0.022124302), (100, 0.021779122), (145, 0.020460771), (179, 0.019821487) ]

nueva_lista = list(map(lambda tupla: tupla[0], lista_de_tuplas))
```

Lo que hace es recorrer `lista_de_tuplas` y devolver el primer elemento de cada tupla.